# Text cut with wkhtmltopdf-binary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf, wkhtmltopdf-binary

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

Above two gems are used.but the issue i'm getting text cuts when page breaks. like in screenshot

[image]

I'm using this piece of lines of code:-

```
  <%if current_company&.po_term.present?%>
    <div class="row po_term_condtions" style="page-break-before: always;">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12" style="page-break-inside:avoid !important;">
        <strong> PO Terms: </strong>
        <%=current_company&.po_term&.po_description.html_safe%>
      </div>
    </div>
  <%end%>
```

however i already tried some suggestions previous asked question
but seems doesn't work

```
page-break-inside:avoid !important;
page-break-inside:avoid; display: inline; // display: block;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your text seems to go under the footer, so first make sure that you set a margin for your footer when you call WickedPDF:

```
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
  html,
  margin: { top: 30, bottom: 30, left: 30, right: 30 },
  header: { content: html_header, spacing: 10 },
  footer: { content: html_footer, spacing: 10 }
)
```

You might have to experiment, I noticed that `wkhtmltopdf` can have different results depending on the version, and I remember some versions ignoring the css page-break attributes.

Also, If you can't get it to work with: `page-break-inside: avoid !important;` then you can try `page-break-before: always;`

Comment: you could see in code i already used `page-break-before: always;` to start that pieces of code to start it from new page.

Comment: Well, in this case if your whole description doesn't fit on a page then there is nothing you'll be able to do. You can try reducing your font-size until it fits, or avoiding page-breaks in `<p>` tags to avoid paragraphs that span two pages, but the behavior in your screenshot seems to suggest either a margin issue, or that the whole content is longer that it fits on the page.